# Refactoring if statement based on a hash key

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, hash-map

I have to call Article.`to_draft`/`to_archive`/`publish` method depending on the *presence* of the corresponding key in the `params` hash.

I do, however, have no idea to implement it *properly*.

```
def update_state
  method = if params[:draft].present?
             :to_draft
           elsif params[:archived].present?
             :to_archive
           else
             :publish
           end
  @article.send method
end
```

The code works, but the number of possible states of an article will probably grow in the future.

I would like to have a hash like this:

```
{ draft: :to_draft, archived: :to_archive, default: :publish }
```

and let `#update_state` decide what should be called, based on the `params` hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)

```
ARTICLE_ACTIONS = { :draft => :to_draft,
                    :archived => :to_archive,
                    :default => :publish 
                  }

def update_state
  state = [:draft, :archived, :default]
             .find {|state| params[state].present?}
  @article.send ARTICLE_ACTIONS[state]
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't explain it well.
`params` is a hash provided by rails controller.
it does NOT contain the names of the corresponding methods (:draft => :to_draft etc.). I have to call what's needed manually

Comment: Browser sends an HTTP request, with one of the possible states (draft, archived).

Based on this, I have to call one of the @article methods: @article.`to_draft` if params contains 'draft' or @article`to_archive` if params contains `archived` or @article.`publish` if none are provided

Comment: @justso you may build the hash yourself, answer updated

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is already but I think it can be simplified further by using routes. Like

```
post "article/:state", to: "articles#update_state"
```

and then you can simply call

```
["draft", "archived", "default"].includes?(params[:state]) && @article.send(params[:state])
```

Comment: It's an security vulnerability

Comment: A question having an accepted answer isn't a problem, more reviews are always welcome when they have new suggestions like this.

Comment: @justso I think it can be bypassed, I have edited my answer though.